# ¿Cómo puedo parar el movimiento de un objeto en el mismo frame en el que dejo de pulsar un botón en Unity?

Tags: unity2d, rigidbody

El código que tengo para el movimiento es muy simple:

float inputMovimiento = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(inputMovimiento * velocidad, rigidbody.velocity.y);

¿Tendría que cambiar algo para lograr el efecto que quiero o me podría servir?
Lo que quiero es que una vez soltado el botón de dirección el objeto frene en el mismo frame ya que quiero que siempre salte sin inercia horizontal es decir un salto limpio totalmente vertical y no tener que esperar a que el objeto frene para poder saltar.

Comment: Podría haber alguna solución sin tocar el codigo? ajustando valores del rigidbody materiales del sprite etc...?